# Why when use transform construction with pd.Series i'm getting Error: Mismatch Length

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7, junit-jupiter

I have a big `pandas.DataFrame` (~2.5 million rows) with 10 columns. I need to fill column `noshow_label`, i group data by column `event_label` and if in column `event_action` there is a value `no_show` then i need to paste `True` else i need paste `False`.
To do that i use this construction:

```
data['noshow_label'] = data.groupby('event_label')['event_action'].transform(lambda x: 'no_show' in x.values)
```

When i tried to start this code, it raised an error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2328271 elements, new values have 2328273 elements
```

> For note: Column `event_action` contains values like `no_show`, `show_widget`, `test_passed`. 
>   Column 'event_label`contains labels names like`123123-A`, '123123-B' ...

Do you have any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Can you share example of data? For instance, `df.head()` result.

Comment: @E.Zeytinci , it was problem with data in DataFrame, i've add the answer, thank you that u spend a time to my question ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with data, my DataFrame has values like 'NULL' in group column, when i've delete them from my sample, problem has gone.